# i7 4770 Cheap Deal vs i7 6700

Tags: gaming, processor

I got an offer to buy a used Core i7-4770 with Asus Motherboard and 16 Gigs of DDR3 RAM for 200 Euros. This offer comes to pass very good because I am thinking about upgrading my computer.

Currently, I use an AMD FX-6300 on an MSI Board which recently started having issues on boot. GPU is the Sapphire R9 270X, but I will upgrade to an GTX 1070 soon.

My question now is, should I take that deal for 200 Euros or should I save some more money to take a new i7-6700 with DDR4 instead. How is the Performance to Value comparison?
I compared the two CPUs using [CPUBenchmark.net](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=1907&cmp%5B%5D=2598) and the Benchmark Points are different by just 200, which does not seem much compared to the difference from my FX-6300 to the i7's (which is about 3k Points difference).

In case you need some information about my main usage of the PC, I play a lot of games like Rainbow Six Siege, The Division, Overwatch, Paragon (guess that's the cpu-heaviest game of those) and I also do a lot of rendering to MP4 (live and non-live).

Comment: "Is it worth it?" questions are off topic as primarily opinion based. Used hardware is especially difficult, as we have no way of knowing the condition it is in. I unfortunately see no way to save this question besides writing a new question on top of it.

Comment: Both are 'good enough' - and at that price the used PC feels like a steal.

Comment: The used PC is old "Server Hardware" of a company where I work, that's why I can get it at this price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *seriously* consider the newer chip for rendering.
I shall weigh up the + / - as if we refer to upgrading to the newer CPU.

**-** It has been shown on TOM's hardware many times that there is little difference for gaming, due to the CPU clock-speed being a big factor in games still. Consider this a small minus as CPU has VERY little effect on game performance (it's all about GPU, baby!)

**-** You will need to buy new RAM as you stated, and it's not really much better in performance for games... Video it is, but only a little bit.

**+** Power usage / thermal control is a LOT better on the 6000's, so it will distract your gaming a lot less with quieter fans.

**+** Video encoding MUCH faster on the new i7's if the software is optimised for it (it will be).

**+** (this is the one that got me) Upgrading Mobo means you get all the sweet new features such as USB3.1 and type-C connectors. Future-you will thank you for this investment.

Also, EUR200 is too much for that old CPU. I mean, performance-per-dollar it's OK, but if you really look hard for second-hand machines you will find one (probably with case and PSU) for half that price.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question can be opinion based and I am not going to take that road. Hovewer I'll argue, that it is worth buying newer hardware for 'future-proofing' like: DDR4 support, Microsoft presumably says it's dropping Windows 10 support for older hardware than Skylake ([source](http://www.theverge.com/2016/1/16/10780876/microsoft-windows-support-policy-new-processors-skylake)).

On the other hand, the 200 Euro deal you describe is indeed profitable, and the hardware will serve your purpose for years to come (especially when paired with 1080).

The choice is still up to you though.